# When to use singular or plural resource names in RAML

Tags: resources, mule, anypoint-studio, raml

I am writing my first RAML for a Mule project and had a query around naming convention.  At the moment I have a requirement where a customer will make a single payment.  So I have a /payment resource.  If a new requirement to be able to make multiple payments was introduced later how would the resources be shown in RAML?

Will the resource for a single payment look like POST:/payments/payment

I have been told that the paths should be no more than 4 levels so I think the above standard would easily go above 4 levels in some cases and also I may repeat GET and POST etc under each single and plural resource name with the one difference being the request being a collection instead  of just an object.

Also, if I was looking at resources for e.g. a customer's order should I include the order resource e.g.
GET: /customer/{customerId}/order/{orderId}
or is it best practice to go straight to the orderId?
GET: /customer/{customerId}/{orderId}

Finally, when should I use a parameter instead or a resource URI?

I see alot of examples on the web but not much on conventions so far so just wanted to check my understanding is correct so not to have a rewrite in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This link is good resource. http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

There is no established rule i think, I follow plural all the time and singularity is contextual based on the service call.

GET: /customers/ - Get all consumers
GET: /customer/{customerId} - Gets singular customer

> is it best practice to go straight to the orderId?

It is best practice to to highlight relation between the resources as customers//orders//items// ..

Answer (score 1):

**singular** uses for singleton resource, which returns a single object, for example `users/{userID}/adress`. HTTP methods:

- GET/HEAD(get) ✅
- POST(create) ❌
- PUT(replace) ✅
- PATCH(Partial update) ✅
- DELETE(remove) ❌

**plural** uses for collection resource, which returns a list of the objects, for example `users/{userID}/orders/` HTTP methods:

- GET/HEAD(get) ✅
- POST(create) ✅
- PUT(replace) ❌
- PATCH(Partial update) ✅ used for batch update objects in the collection
- DELETE(remove) ❌

**entity** uses as subresource with id in the collection resource, for example `users/{userID}`. HTTP methods:

- GET/HEAD(get) ✅
- POST(create) ❌
- PUT(replace) ✅
- PATCH(Partial update) ✅
- DELETE(remove) ✅